# Knockout.js Binding param to Data-Target returning object instead of text (Accordion)

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js, view

New to Knockout.Js and just about getting my head around the data-bindings after three days...

I have created a dynamic accordion and when doing my data-bind with the attr: {'data-target': '#' + RecipeName' i get back Data-target=#[object object] I understand that i can get back the name
of the parameter if i used data-bind="text: RecipeName" (But i need to append the # to it
to allow my accordion to be opened on the correct Id..)

I have looked online and i can't seem to find a sufficient answer. I have tried google
dev tools to change the #[object object] to the value im expecting and it works fine.

Please can someone explain why this happens and what is needed to resolve.. I guess its pretty straight forward?

```
<section id="results" style="margin-top: 1em;">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover accordion">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Set Next</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Bench</th>
                    <th>Transacted</th>
                    <th>Receipe Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Stages">

                *****<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#' + RecipeName}">*****
                    <td data-bind="css: CellClass">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="attr: {'data-id': Id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveReason">@Html.LocalisedStringFor(model => model.MoveToStageText)</button>
                        <a class="text" data-bind="attr: {'data-id': Id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveReason"><span>@Html.LocalisedStringFor(model => model.CurrentPositionText)</span></a>
                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: ProcessName"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: BenchName"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: TransactionStatus"></span></td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: RecipeName"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="" class="accordion-body collapse" data-bind="attr: {'id':RecipeName}">
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <div class="accordion-inner" data-bind="foreach: $parent.Stages">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <span data-bind="text: StepName"></span></li>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="attr: {'data-id': Id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moveReason">@Html.LocalisedStringFor(model => model.MoveToStageText)</button>
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

This is the result it returns

[image: Visual of what it returning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#' + RecipeName}">`

needs to be

`<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#' + RecipeName()}">`

the other option would be to put a property on your viewmodel that does the logic you need  like

```
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.RecipeName = ko.observable();
  self.RecipeNameHash = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return '#' + self.RecipeName();
  });
}
```

then the table row becomes

`<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': RecipeNameHash}">`

Comment: Thank you so much!! your answer worked for me.. unfortunately i can't upvote yet but i will vote up when it is possible!!

Comment: slight tweek <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#' + RecipeName()}"> Saved me hours of pain. Thank you very much.